# Installing a keylayout file (.kl) with android app (.apk)

Tags: android, android-ndk, keyboard

i have tried and searched for days and was unable to come up with any solution for my problem:

I am trying to install a .kl file in /system/usr/keylayout to remap some keyboard keys for my app. I have the proper .kl file in the right format: Vender_XXXX_Product_XXXX.kl and it works if i copy it by using root explorer.

But I want it to be install (without root) by installing my app. Which means it has to be include in the .apk file and copied during installation!?

My approach so far was either with using a receiver and the QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS intent. 
For that a .kcm file is needed. That did not work with my phone (Galaxy S3). I do not know why but it does not show the PHYSICAL_KEYBOARD settings item in settings :(

Anyways i think/hope the better way is by NDK:
I tried using the ndk and was able to integrate some native c into my application but no "source" files like my .kl file.
I was hoping that a device.mk file would somehow be able to copy my .kl file to /system like so:
device.mk
   PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += 
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/Vendor_XXXX_Product_XXXX.kl:system/usr/keylayout/Vendor_XXXX_Product_XXXX.kl

Is that at all possible? To use the NDK to "install" a file to /system automatically while installing the actual apk?
And if so how do you do that? I am confused about the whole makefile thing and NDK. Never use that before and I am quite bad with c.

If any of you guys know how to do what I am asking ... please let me know. It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to install a keylayout file? They define behaviour for keyboard-like hardware and are put together by the people that write the device drivers. The naming scheme is related to the registration of the driver. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

It's not impossible to install a .kcm file with an apk package. In fact that is just how layout apps do it. You are on the right track with the QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT.

I wanted to install a .kl file, just like you, but I couldn't find any good info on it. So instead I just used the map keyword in my .kcm file, it has the exact same effect.

Check out my source here, where I allow the user to add the se_sv_dvorak layout kcm without rooting the phone: https://github.com/innsmouthrain/se_sv_dvorak

Comment: Hi innsmouth.rain, I will have a look tonight and try your suggestions. Thank you very much for your answer...

Comment: I try using .kcm instead of .kl and it work.  However I still can't figure why .kl not work.

Comment: Link now broken. Fork of example linked above:
https://github.com/abbeyanke/se_sv_dvorak

Comment: Where are you putting your .kcm files on unrooted Android devices to get them to work?

Comment: The github link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

> But I want it to be install (without root) by installing my app.

That is not possible. Apps do not have write access to `/system/usr/`, unless they are running as root.

> To use the NDK to "install" a file to /system automatically while installing the actual apk?

It is doubly impossible:

- Your app does not get control when installing
- Code written using the NDK does not gain any additional OS rights, and so such code cannot write to `/system/usr/`, except when running as root

Comment: Fist of: Thank you very much for you quick answer. You are - as far as I could figure out - correct. BUT: Why do those Vendor.kl files exists than? Their purpose is to be installed to /system/usr/keylayout/ and are write in plain text so that they are easily created.

Comment: @user3072250: "Why do those Vendor.kl files exists than?" -- I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Android system is read only by default. Only remounting as read-write enables writing to system. Remount is root only command. These keylayout *.kl files ship with smartphone and are for bluetooth earphones, joysticks like Sony Playstation 3, Microsoft Xbox 360 game controller, Nintendo wiimote, car audio systems. They translate device specific signals to Android understandable preset keypress events, they behave in every active window/ app diferently. Thet are preset with smartphone maker like these apps which come out of box with each new smartphone. It is commercial and unless you pay to smartphone maker they do not put keylayouts for competitors or developers, everyday users.
Unknown device uses by Android generic.kl keylayout and gives in every active app/ window and launcher very different keypresses.

Solution one: root Android OS and push your *.kl file to system.

Solution two: code your app to behave as you want if keypress event occurs. Let user set input device in app options manually. So keypress A and input option 'joystick' triggers custom response from your app.
Solution three: pay money to your app target smartphone maker and they update Android OS with your custom *.kl file. Very expensive and business level of app making.