# How to include the Key Layout in a Key Character Map File

Tags: android, android-ndk, keyboard-layout

I want to use an azerty keyboard on a Android projector but the physical keyboard layouts are missing.
So I tried adding it myself making a custom layout and install it via APK.
I found a nice example of code on: 
https://sites.google.com/site/polishhardwarekbd/

I found both kl and kcm azerty files on 
https://github.com/ranfyy/eee-qwertz

But I don't understand how to include the kl file in the apk as questioned here:
[Installing a keylayout file (.kl) with android app (.apk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412044/installing-a-keylayout-file-kl-with-android-app-apk)

A comment from innsmouth.rain makes me think I could bundle the two files together.

> I just used the map keyword in my .kcm file, it has the exact same effect.
>   Unfortunately the link to the example file is broken.

The documentation is split, never mixed.
https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files
https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-character-map-files

Could anybody point me to an example of a kcm file mixing the layout ?

Answer (score 0):

The link is dead but there is a fork of that example here:
https://github.com/abbeyanke/se_sv_dvorak

As you can see he is using the map keyword within the .kcm file:

`map key 86 HENKAN`

I haven't tested this but I will when I get home.